# Idiom/word for someone who kowtows to his superiors and kicks his subordinates

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Apparently, a "bicycle rider" is "a current German idiom for someone who kowtows to his superiors and kicks his subordinates". (Source: [Hannah Arendt, *Eichmann in Jerusalem*](http://books.google.com/books?id=yGoxZEdw36oC&pg=PA130).)

Any similar expression in English to describe this sort of person?

Answer (score 2):

Someone who *kisses  up and kicks  down*,  is used to refer to the context you describe:

> - I heard the phrase **“kissing up and kicking down”** first during discussions about John Bolton, a Bush nomination for the US representative to the UN. Its meaning is probably obvious, but in case it isn’t, here’s a very brief explanation. *It means being super nice to people with power over one, and taking it out on people over whom one has some power.* The power needn’t be much more than a matter of rank or class. Someone who is rude to the cleaning staff, while super nice to higher administrators is following the pattern.

Note this neologism,  Bootlickocracy:

> One persistent and defining feature of such an environment is dominant use of **"kiss up, kick down"** principle by middle level managers. We will call such an environment  a bootlickocracy.
>
> The prevalence of  bootlickocracy  in large IT organizations can be viewed as a side effect of dominance of  aggressive but incompetent managers who are colloquially called "empty suits".  More often they are authoritarians and very often Double High Authoritarians).

Source:http://www.softpanorama.org/Skeptics/IT_skeptic/bootlickocracy.shtml

Source: http://feministphilosophers.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/kissing-up-kicking-down-and-tenure/

Answer (score 1):

Two-faced liar? Slimy bastard?

Suck up
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suck+up

It describes one half of this without necessarily pointing out the kicking down part.

Still a "sheep" or suck up goes along with the strong say and just passes it along to the "lower ones". Maybe not effectively so.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/thesaurus.php?term=suck+up

The most close one seems to be "[teachers pet](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Teacher%27s%20pet&defid=260572)". In this case it would be "bosses pet" if you want to adapt it to some specific person.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to translate this term, I would probably do so literally: *cyclist*. After all, the pun works in all languages. In German this is indeed a very common idiom, used regularly by practically everyone who has a typical office job and thinks they are not a specimen.

I have often wondered why German didn't seem to have a word for *bully*, as I often needed one. (The dictionary translation *Tyrann* doesn't really fit, since a Tyrann is a despot with strong connotations of being a Greek monarch.)

The main difference between *Radfahrer* and *bully* seems to be the that the former occurs in an office environment and the latter at school. That a Radfahrer is less physically violent is just a natural consequence.

Comment: Yes I think *cyclist* is indeed a very good pun. Unfortunately it is not popularly used in the English language. Perhaps all we need to do is to popularize it.

Comment: The problem is of course that the first time you use it you must explain the pun. Maybe *office bully* could work instead?

Answer (score 0):

Bootlicker synonyms in English don't convey the meaning of being harsh on subordinates, but you could make this up. How about a "toady tyrant", or a "despotic brown-nose"?